# my gradle in android studio doesn't work anymore

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

when I wanted to add a dependencie gradle got a problem in my gradle
I mean when I create a new project this problem there is in other project

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I removed gradle and install the gradle again to solved the problem but not worked

Answer (score 0):

The only error you showed is in your third screenshot.
And the error there is, that you try to use Groovy DSL syntax in a Kotlin DSL file.
Use proper Kotlin DSL syntax, and it will work.